# Perform Certain task of LED blink on atmega328p

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

Build a modular program using two switches and two LEDs on a atmega328p. Follow the below conditions:

```
Switch-I   Switch-II   LED 1 state   LED 2 state
 open         open         LOW           LOW
 open         close        LOW           HIGH
 close        open         HIGH          LOW
 close        close    Toggle LED     Toggle LED
```

We have also to make two functions :
**GPIOConfig(Pin, mode)**
Purpose: The function is used to configure the mode of the pin.
Pin: The Atmega328P port pin which need to be configured.
Mode: direction of the pin in INPUT or OUTPUT. In case of INPUT, the mode is required to be
configured for PULLUP configuration along with INPUT.
**GPIOPinWrite(pin, state)**
Purpose: The function is used to write LOW or HIGH state to GPIO pin.
Pin: The Atmega328P pin used to write LOW or HIGH state.
State: LOW or HIGH
Here is the code which I have written:

```
#include"GPIO.h"
#include<stdint.h>
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#define SET_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT|= (1<<BIT)
#define CLR_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT&= ~(1<<BIT)
//#define TOGGLE_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT^= (1<<BIT)
void GPIOConfig(uint8_t PORT,uint8_t PIN);
void GPIOPinWrite(uint8_t PIN,char* STATE);
int main()
{
    GPIOConfig(DDRD,PD7);
    GPIOConfig(DDRD,PD6);
    GPIOConfig(DDRD,PD3);
    GPIOConfig(DDRD,PD2);
    //GPIOConfig();// Insert code
    while(1)
    {
     //GPIOPinRead();
     uint8_t PIN_READ=0x00; // 00000000
     if(PIN_READ==PIND)
        if ((PIN_READ & (1<<PD2)) && PIN_READ & (1<<PD3)) // (00000100)& (00000100) //Pooling
        {
            while(1)
            {
           GPIOPinWrite(PD7,"HIGH");
           GPIOPinWrite(PD6,"HIGH");
           _delay_ms(1000);
           GPIOPinWrite(PD7,"LOW");
           GPIOPinWrite(PD6,"LOW");
           _delay_ms(1000);
            }
        }
        else if((PIN_READ & (1<<PD2)))//&& (PIN_READ & ~(1<<PD3)))
        {
            GPIOPinWrite(PD7,"HIGH");
        }
        else if((PIN_READ & (1<<PD3)))// && (PIN_READ & (1<<PD2)))
        {
            GPIOPinWrite(PD6,"HIGH");
        }
        else
        {
            GPIOPinWrite(PD7,"LOW");
            GPIOPinWrite(PD6,"LOW");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void GPIOConfig(uint8_t PORT,uint8_t PIN)
{
if(PIN==PD6 || PIN==PD7)
{
    SET_BIT(PORT,PIN);
}
else if(PIN==PD2 || PIN==PD3)
{
    SET_BIT(PORT,PIN);         // PD7,PD6 as output - LED is connected
    CLR_BIT(PORTD,PIN);        // Making it a pull up configuration
}
}
void GPIOPinWrite(uint8_t PIN,char* STATE)
{
if(STATE=="HIGH")
    SET_BIT(PORTD,PIN);
else if(STATE=="LOW")
    CLR_BIT(PORTD,PIN);
}
```

According to me the Logic is correct but the decleration and initialisation of variables and Pins are not correct that is why my LED is not blinking. Although the code does not show any error in the codeblocks.
Do check this code and please help to find out the problem and the solution to this.

Comment: Please enable all the possible warnings in your compiler. It's probably going to tell you that you are comparing a `char*` to `const char*` and that it is not doing what you expect it to do. Besides the non working MCU code: look at a C tutorial as you still have to learn some more about C.

Answer (score 3):

This code has several fundamental problems.

The `DDRD` in main() is supposedly a reference to the actual register, fetched from some register map header. Then you pass the *value* of this register to a function accepting `uint8_t PORT`. The connection to the actual register is lost and your functions end up manipulating some local variable instead of the actual register.

Just forget about writing bloatware function layers, string comparisons and other irrelevant things on top of very basic stuff. Instead write everything out on a single, readable line: `DDRD = PD7 | PD6 | PD3 | PD2;` etc, assuming these should be outputs. Same for pull registers.

A detailed guide for how to do this without a bloatware library can be found here:
[How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/questions/276290)

Comment: As for how to actually design a proper hardware abstraction layer on top of driver code, that's rather qualified work. Don't expect to be doing that before you have 5+ years of full time embedded C experience, otherwise the chance of getting it right is non-existent.